# Invisible Ubuntu-sdk menu

Tags: menu, ubuntu-sdk, awesome

I am planning to develop mobile programs using ubuntu-sdk, but my window manager is awesome(http://awesome.naquadah.org/) and menu of ubuntu-sdk is not visible at all.
All other programs work perfectly except only one ubuntu-sdk.

Needed to be fixed to have normal menu like usual Qt Creator has.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Gnome3 as my window manager, so not aware about awesome. But this workaround worked for me

sudo apt-get remove appmenu-qt5

Souce : [Link to bug report with work around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1307619)

Do let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Why was the answer down voted?